# Update data in database based on order id in Django

Tags: django, database, insert-update

I am new in Django. 
I want to update the value in the database based on the order id. Therefore, every order id has different updates. But, i only can update the last item that i add to the order. And every previous orders that i have, will directly follow the update from the last item.

models.py

```
 class OrderItem(models.Model):
     Table_No = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
     FoodId = models.TextField()
     Item = models.TextField()
     Qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=0)
     Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
     TotalPrice = models.TextField()
     Note = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
     OrderId = models.TextField(max_length=5, null=True)

     FoodStatus = (
         ('1', 'Has been ordered'),
         ('2', 'cooked'),
         ('3', 'ready to be served'),
         ('4', 'done'),
     )
     food_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=FoodStatus)
```

views.py

```
def kitchen_view(request):
    chef_view = OrderItem.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        order_id = request.POST.get("OrderId")
        status = OrderItem.objects.filter(OrderId=request.POST.get("OrderId")) 
        status.status1 = OrderItem.objects.update(food_status=request.POST.get("food_status"))
    return render(request, 'restaurants/kitchen_page.html', {'chef_view': chef_view})
```

kitchen_page.html

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
        {% csrf_token %}                
        {% for order in chef_view %}    
            <table width="800">
                <tr>
                    <th width="800">Table Number</th>           
                    <th width="800">Item</th>                   
                    <th width="800">Quantity</th>               
                    <th width="800">Price</th>                  
                    <th width="800">Note</th>                   
                    <th width="800">Order Id</th>               
                    <th width="800">Status</th>                 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="800">{{ order.Table_No }}</td>   
                    <td width="800">{{ order.Item }}</td>       
                    <td width="800">{{ order.Qty }}</td>    
                    <td width="800">{{ order.Price }}</td>      
                    <td width="800">{{ order.Note }}</td>       
                    <td width="800">{{ order.OrderId }}</td>    
                    <td width="800">{{ order.food_status }}     
                        <input type="text" name="food_status">
                </tr>
            </table>
        {% endfor %}
        <br><a href='' button onclick="myFunction()"><input type="submit" value="Change Status"></button>
    </form>
```

The result should be able to update the food_status based on the order_id. Therefore, every order_id may have different food_status and show it to the template.

Anyone can help me to solve this problem? I really need the help to solve this issue. Really appreciate.

Comment: Where is the `food_status` field in the model that you are mentioning here?

Comment: i have updated my models.py

Comment: Post your form from kitchen_page.html. It is saving locally on my pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so real problem is that your form is incorrect - you are not sending `OrderId` to view. Here's quickfix to it:

kitchen_page.html:

```
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <table width="800">
        <tr>
            <th width="800">Table Number</th>
            <th width="800">Item</th>
            <th width="800">Quantity</th>
            <th width="800">Price</th>
            <th width="800">Note</th>
            <th width="800">Order Id</th>
            <th width="800">Status</th>
        </tr>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for order in chef_view %}
            <tr>
                <td width="800">{{ order.Table_No }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.Item }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.Qty }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.Price }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.Note }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.OrderId }}</td>
                <td width="800">{{ order.food_status }}
                    <input type="text" name="food_status" value="{{ order.food_status }}">
            </tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="OrderId" value="{{ order.OrderId }}">
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <br><button type="submit" value="Change Status">Change Status</button>
</form>
```

views.py:

```py
def kitchen_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        order_ids = request.POST.getlist("OrderId")
        food_statuses = request.POST.getlist("food_status")
        for i in range(len(order_ids)):
            OrderItem.objects.filter(OrderId=order_ids[i]).update(food_status=food_statuses[i])
    chef_view = OrderItem.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'restaurants/kitchen_page.html', {'chef_view': chef_view})
```

Comment: i have tried your codes, and it works only when saving the last item added into database. If i change the food_status on previous items, they do not save into database. Do you know why and how to solve this issue?

Comment: @Eve11 checkout new code, it can save multiple fields at once.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have tried your codes, and it works by saving the selected order id into database. By when i want to change another food_status from another order id and save it into db, it delete the other changes. Is there a way to update the selection changes, save them, and when updating another one, the previous update still there?

Comment: When you click submit button, it will update `food_status` from the form to db, exactly as they are in form. It is not deleting, just updating to the ones you send them. I've updated code to get latest values in form, but the problem will still be there if you use multiple tabs or so, and there is no solution without javascript or multiple forms.

Comment: I have tried your codes and seems like it works similar with the previous one. Do you mean, when updating one food_status, that food_status cannot remain in the db? therefore when updating another food_status from another order id, the previous food_status cannot be seen again?

Comment: No, I meant that it should be updating correctly, as long as you use 1 tab and no ajax. I wonder which `OrderId` in your database actually set. Are they unique? If they are not, it's possible your values can be overwritten by same request.

Comment: ah i see. The OrderId is unique because i have set it in random. Thus, it is possible to keep the previous food_status changes showed in the template after changing another food_status when i am using 1 tab only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193310/discussion-between-gasanov-and-eve11).

Comment: hi @Gasanov , i think there is something error with the chat, because i suddenly cannot get into the room although i have refresh the page

Comment: @Eve11 yeah, I have that as well. Let's wait till they fix it.

Comment: @Eve11 it's back

Answer (score 1):

Previously stored filtered objects are not being updated as you have

```
status = OrderItem.objects.filter(OrderId=request.POST.get("OrderId"))
```

but when you are updating them, you should be updating the already filtered objects like

```
status = status.update(food_status=request.POST.get("food_status"))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i change it to this code, but it does not save into the database. Do you know why it does not save into db?

Comment: it shows an error which is AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save'

Answer (score 0):

You can update multiple objects at once including the filter in a single line as:

```
status = OrderItem.objects.filter(OrderId=request.POST.get("OrderId")).update(food_status=request.POST.get("food_status"))
```

The problem in your code:

```
status.status1 = OrderItem.objects.update(food_status=request.POST.get("food_status"))
```

was that you were not using the filter, instead you tried updating the **status1 field**(Can't see a status1 field in your model) using `status.status1`.

Comment: i have tried this, but the changes do not save into the database.  Do you know why it does not save into db?

Comment: Are you sure that you have declared the forms correctly?

Comment: yes. But i don't know why it cannot be saved into db